# Issue with coherence POF annotation implementation

Tags: oracle-coherence

I have a coherence 3.7 cluster. I am trying to connect to it using a simple java application client. if I try this with java serialization implementation and POF disabled it works fine for me. But when i enable POF I start getting exception. below is the stack trace. I have my pof-config at both client and cluster side. any hints about what could be causing this issue would be very helpful.

```
2012-09-04 13:40:04.811/1.531 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.4 <Error> (thread=ExtendTcpCacheService:TcpInitiator, member=n/a): An exception occurred while encoding a OpenConnectionRequest for Service=ExtendTcpCacheService:TcpInitiator: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown user type: com.tangosol.util.UUID
at com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext.getUserTypeIdentifier(ConfigurablePofContext.java:430)
at com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext.getUserTypeIdentifier(ConfigurablePofContext.java:419)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.extend.Channel.getUserTypeIdentifier(Channel.CDB:7)
at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferWriter.writeUserType(PofBufferWriter.java:1671)
at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferWriter.writeObject(PofBufferWriter.java:1623)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to message you're getting, tcp initiator is failing because it cannot serialize Coherence type (*com.tangosol.util.UUID*). Did you include the default pof config in your pof config file?

Comment: No I did not. It started working fine once I included the default POF config. Thanks.